# MS SQL Server - Frequent Deadlock Issues

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

**Target Database :** MS SQL Server 2012

**Requirement :** Maintain summary of user’s workload in a table. Following is the table structure used to maintain this summary. Table is getting updated on modification of status of workitem assigned to user.

- PARTICIPANT_ID   varchar NO  PK, Unique non clustered index
- OFFERED_COUNT    numeric YES
- ALLOCATED_COUNT  numeric YES
- STARTED_COUNT    numeric YES
- SUSPENDED_COUNT  numeric YES

**Issue :** We are facing frequent deadlocks on this table. Herewith I have attached deadlock graph for reference.

**Investigation done so far :**

- Target Rows (Updates) in deadlocks are independent to each other so no question of one transaction waiting for other to relinquish lock.Even inserts to the table becomes part of deadlock.
- Same transaction is working with similar concurrent load in Oracle.
- Suspecting that table is getting locked instead of particular row, we even tried to disable escalation of locks at a table using following command but deadlocks persisted.

**ALTER TABLE Table_name SET (LOCK_ESCALATION DISABLE)**

***Deadlock graph***

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process133f03d498" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process133f03d498" taskpriority="0" logused="3308" waitresource="RID: 11:1:819250:71" waittime="2377" ownerId="29578701" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-11-09T09:29:43.397" XDES="0x10b0b716a8" lockMode="U" schedulerid="6" kpid="7332" status="suspended" spid="210" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-11-09T09:29:45.977" lastbatchcompleted="2017-11-09T09:29:45.397" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.397" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="PAWSPPAS02" hostpid="123" loginname="STG_SUITE_SSO" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="29578701" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" sqlhandle="0x02000000ee409c1fd278abb7f476707399656cbedec9d1960000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update [RS_WI_PARTICIPANT_SUMM] set [ALLOCATED_COUNT]=[ALLOCATED_COUNT]-1 where [PARTICIPANT_ID]= @P0    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))update [RS_WI_PARTICIPANT_SUMM] set [ALLOCATED_COUNT]=[ALLOCATED_COUNT]-1 where [PARTICIPANT_ID]= @P0    </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="processc70140188" taskpriority="0" logused="85392" waitresource="RID: 11:1:819250:30" waittime="2196" ownerId="29574187" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-11-09T09:29:16.427" XDES="0x1150f5d6a8" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="384" status="suspended" spid="141" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-11-09T09:29:46.157" lastbatchcompleted="2017-11-09T09:29:45.470" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.470" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="PAWSPPAS02" hostpid="123" loginname="STG_SUITE_SSO" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="29574187" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" sqlhandle="0x020000001c3c261d27cfa98e13a9cb06f6c30e40cfcaa4a50000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update [RS_WI_PARTICIPANT_SUMM] set [ALLOCATED_COUNT]=[ALLOCATED_COUNT]+1 where [PARTICIPANT_ID]= @P0    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))update [RS_WI_PARTICIPANT_SUMM] set [ALLOCATED_COUNT]=[ALLOCATED_COUNT]+1 where [PARTICIPANT_ID]= @P0    </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <ridlock fileid="1" pageid="819250" dbid="11" objectname="STG_SUITE_SSO.dbo.RS_WI_PARTICIPANT_SUMM" id="lock1236714900" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057599198953472">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="processc70140188" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process133f03d498" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </ridlock>
  <ridlock fileid="1" pageid="819250" dbid="11" objectname="STG_SUITE_SSO.dbo.RS_WI_PARTICIPANT_SUMM" id="lockdacb14f00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057599198953472">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process133f03d498" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="processc70140188" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </ridlock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on this table? How many indexes include `[PARTICIPANT_ID]` as the first column? My reasoning is: that in your case dead locks occur because of different indexes being used by different processes. If you add an index hint to force all processes to use the same index, your problems **may** go away. SQL Server issues locks on the index and table separately, therefore if different indexes used by different processes, problems may happen.

Comment: Alex, We do have only one non clustered index on [PARTICIPANT_ID] column. Thanks for prompt response.

Comment: How big is the table? If it is small enough then simple table scans are a possibility as well.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291473/why-is-this-sql-server-query-deadlocking

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287575/sql-deadlock-with-select-update-operations-on-a-table

Comment: Is PARTICIPANT_ID unique in [RS_WI_PARTICIPANT_SUMM] ?

Comment: If you configure _read commited snapshot isolation_, your problems _might_ disappear.

Comment: @Alex, Table has approx. 84 records.

Comment: @sepupic, PARTICIPANT_ID is PK and unique in table

Comment: @Nick, we already have read commited snapshot isolation in place at DB.

Comment: OK - between yourself and @Remus your well beyond any advice I could give

Comment: >>>PARTICIPANT_ID is PK and unique in tabl<<< This means only that you have at least 2 updates in one transaction. So you have 2 PARTICIPANT_ID that are updated in one order, and in another process in the reverse order

Comment: Do you use triggers or linked servers?

Comment: @Alex - we are executing these queries as part of Java application using jTDS JDBC driver.

Answer (score 4):

One thread has updated the row 819250:71 and now wants to update the row 819250:30, the other has updated the row 819250:30 and now wants to update the row 819250:71.

I can only speculate about what is going on here (since you are omitting so many details), but my guess is that the application has some logic that is updating two 'participants' in some sort of exchange and, inside a database transaction, is trying to increase one's amount +1 and then decrease the other one's amount -1. However, the application logic is doing it consistently in opposite order (on thread is doing in a transaction [A+=1, B-=1] while the other is doing it [B+=1, A-=1]). No schema design can prevent this deadlock, only application logic change. Look into *why* concurrent opposite updates are so frequent.

This does not seem to be a issue of using a non-unique non-clustered index on `[PARTICIPANT_ID]`, because in that case the engine would locate the rows 819250:71 and 819250:30 in the same order for both statements and would not deadlock. Hence my conclusion that we have (at least) two update statements in a single transaction that updates two different rows (two `@P0` values) and the app logic is updating the same set of participants in opposite order from 2 transactions (2 requests perhaps).

Furthermore:

```
<process id="498" "RID: 11:1:819250:71" lasttranstarted="2017-11-09T09:29:43.397" lastbatchstarted="2017-11-09T09:29:45.977" lastbatchcompleted="2017-11-09T09:29:45.397"... >
<process id="188" "RID: 11:1:819250:30" lasttranstarted="2017-11-09T09:29:16.427" lastbatchstarted="2017-11-09T09:29:46.157" lastbatchcompleted="2017-11-09T09:29:45.470" ...>
```

If you look at the two transactions:

- process 1 started the transaction at 9:29:43.397, completed a batch at 9:29:45.397 and started the current batch at 9:29:45.977
- process 2 started the transaction at 9:29:16.427, completed a batch at 9:29:45.470 and started the current batch at 9:29:46.157

This time sequence corroborates my hypothesis. The transactions contain a sequence of batches, indicating individual updates (eg. Entity Framework apply changes or similar),  which apply to different rows (different IDs). The IDs are overlapping and the updates are applied in inconsistent order (again, typical behavior of an ORM like EF applying changes).

If my speculation is right, then you should look at locking a higher level logical entity first. If these are *participants*, there must be something they participate into, like a *game*. Before updating the participants, lock the game: eg. using [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) on the `[GAME_ID]` at the start of the transaction. This way the order of updating the participants is no longer dangerous for deadlocks, because the updates are serialized for each game.

Other solution is to *sort* the participants before applying the updates so that every transaction updates the rows in the same order.

> We do have only one non clustered index on [PARTICIPANT_ID] column

Almost certain this should be a clustered index. There are very few cases when having a non-clustered index and a heap make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed analysis. We did dwell upon this scenario but business wise its a very rare scenario that records for both the participants are updated in a different transactions at the same time whereas deadlocks are quite frequent. Secondly, In case participants record does not exists in the table, transaction inserts data to the table. Interestingly we have seen even inserts are participating in deadlocks.

Comment: Additionally we tried to simulate the scenario with Oracle and we could not reproduce any deadlocks so we are suspecting that it is more to do with database than code.

Comment: @Sandeep it would be useful to know what exactly were the statements run in the transactions involved, prior to the deadlock. The deadlock info clearly shows that there were prior statements executed, in both transactions.

Comment: I am a beginner w.r.t. SQL Server. I believe SQL Server avoids deadlocks by killing one of the participating process having low cost. Is there anyway we can found out any details about participating transactions and actual target rows afterwards. If you can share SQL statements for that it will be great help.